# Try-Catch, optional/null, and lambda

Tags: java

Considering the following code :

- obj is not modified after been intialised by service, but, due to try/catch block, it is not considered as effectively final.
  is there a way to avoid this ?
- Does Optional might be considered as a universal method to avoid null checking ? In this example, service would throw exception instead or returning null, or always return Optional ?

  ```
  //to be used outside try/catch block, object must be initialized as null
  SomeObject obj = null;
  try {
      obj = someService.getSomeObject();
  } catch (ServiceException e) {
      LOG.error("Something nasty happened", e);
  }

  //the service could have returned a null object
  if(obj == null) {
      LOG.error("Obj is null");
  }

  //to be used in a lambda, object must be final
  SomeObject objCopy = obj;
  boolean test = someList.stream()
          .anyMatch(o->o.equals(objCopy));
  ```

Comment: 'it is not considered as effectively final' What do you mean by that?

Comment: @LutzHorn, a variable  is considered as effectively final if it's value never changed after it is initialized.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just split the try/catching into a separate method (This is generally good practice as it makes the code more readable. Refer to "Clean Code" by Robert Cecil Martin)

```
final Optional<SomeObject> obj = getObjFromService(someService);
```

...

```
private Optional<SomeObject> getObjFromService(Service someService) {
    try {
        return Optional.of(someService.getSomeObject());
    } catch (ServiceException e) {
        LOG.error("Something nasty happened", e);
    }
    return Optional.empty();
}
```

You could also return null from the method `getObjFromService`, you can still declare the variable final since you-re only assigning it once.

Answer (score 0):

make objCopy final

```
final SomeObject objCopy = obj;
boolean test = someList.stream()
    .anyMatch(o->o.equals(objCopy));
```

Comment: I create a objCopy in this purpose, it is effectively final at this point

Comment: wasn't there in the original question. Sorry